# advertising tx power level in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ads, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am currently programming the peripheral side of an app.  I want to advertise the tx power level, but all i have found as far as tx documentation is:

```
CB_EXTERN NSString * const CBAdvertisementDataTxPowerLevelKey;  // A NSNumber
```

I have tried to implement this in the following way:

```
/** Start advertising
 */
- (IBAction)switchChanged:(id)sender
{

    [self.peripheralManager startAdvertising:@{ CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey : @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID]] }];
    [self.peripheralManager startAdvertising: CBAdvertisementDataTxPowerLevelKey];

}


@end
```

I keep getting a warning on my last line of code saying "Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSString*' to parameter of type 'NSDictionary*'.  I understand that my TxPowerLevelKey is a NSString, but what is NSDictionary referring to?

Comment: It is telling you you can't pass `CBAdvertisementDataTxPowerLevelKey` to `startAdvertising:` because it is a `NSString*` and needs to be an `NSDictionary*` object. The first time you set something to `startAdvertising:` has been done correctly, you have passed an `NSDictionary*` object with a key and object in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other answers have addressed how your dictionary is defined, however, you were looking for a higher level issue; How to transmit the txPower level from an iOS device.

The answer is that currently you can't. After you fixed your code, it compiled and ran, but CoreBluetooth is simply ignoring that key.

As stated by [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheralManager_Class/Reference/CBPeripheralManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CBPeripheralManager/startAdvertising:):

> An optional dictionary containing the data you want to advertise. The
>   possible keys of an advertisementData dictionary are detailed in
>   CBCentralManagerDelegate Protocol Reference. **That said, only two of
>   the keys are supported for peripheral manager objects:
>   CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey and
>   CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey.**

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

In Objective-C, `@{}` is shorthand for `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:(id), ..., nil]`.  The warning indicates the -[PeripheralManager startAdvertising] method is expecting an NSDictionary.  Try wrapping the key in a dictionary with a Boolean True value (represented as an NSNumber object with `@(YES)`):

```
    [self.peripheralManager startAdvertising:@{ CBAdvertisementDataTxPowerLevelKey : @(YES)}];
```

Comment: That worked perfectly thanks teddy.  I was also wondering how my central manager which is on another device is going to read this as the as the tx power level.  How do I address it on the receiving side that will clearly distinguish it from the other UUID's?

Comment: Read the section in the docs on startAdvertising - that key is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't seem to know what an `NSDictionary*` object is please see [the Apple Documentation for NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

But to answer your question the warning

> Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSString*' to parameter of type 'NSDictionary*

which is referring to

```
    [self.peripheralManager startAdvertising: CBAdvertisementDataTxPowerLevelKey];
```

Is because `startAdvertising:` will be declared something like

```
- (void)startAdvertising:(NSDictionary *)start;
```

So it is expecting you to pass in an `NSDictionary*` object whereas at the moment you are passing in an `NSString*` object.

You can resolve this in one of two ways. The first way would be to use the short hand way like you have already done here

```
      [self.peripheralManager startAdvertising:@{ CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey : @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID]] }];
```

Notice that the shorthand version of an `NSDictionary*` object starts at `@{` and ends at `}` so the to declare an `NSDictionary*` object this way it would be something like `@{ Key : Object }` so for you it would be `@{ CBAdvertisementDataTxPowerLevelKey : @(YES) }`

The second way of declaring this would be to do it as I would think of the normal way like :

```
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@(YES), CBAdvertisementDataTxPowerLevelKey, nil]
```

if you have any questions please just ask.

Comment: Thanks. I was also wondering how my central manager which is on another device is going to read this as the as the tx power level. How do I address it on the receiving side that will clearly distinguish it from the other UUID's?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Also you should be asking that as a separate question.

Comment: If i did that then it would be harder to understand. Im saying my app also acts as central on another device.  when that other device receives the advertisement that you just showed me how to implement(i.e. the TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID and the TxPowerLevelKey) how will it know that the TxPowerLevelKey is the Tx power level and not just a set of random numbers. I need to know this to use the Tx Power level in an equation.

Comment: One device is going to advertise and the other device is going to be a  central

Comment: This needs to be asked as a separate question and just reference this question if need be but leave it here you will more than likely not get an answer. Because I don't even understand what you're talking about now.